# How to translate math technical terms?

Tags: notation, definition, convention, translation-request

> What is a good way to translate mathematical technical terms?

This can sometimes be hard because some words have different meanings in some language. For example:

- "eigenwert" (= "eigenvalue" in german) is translated "intrisic value" by [google translate](https://translate.google.de/?ie=UTF-8&hl=en&client=tw-ob#de/en/eigenwert).
- "coprs" (= "division ring" in french) is translated "body" by most of the translators, e.g. [google](https://translate.google.de/?ie=UTF-8&hl=en&client=tw-ob#fr/en/corps), [Linguee](http://www.linguee.com/french-english/translation/corps.html), etc.

In particular, I would like to know how to say "manifolds" in spanish.

Comment: Use Google Translate.

Comment: http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variedad

Comment: variedad diferenciable

Comment: @PrasunBiswas As I pointed out in my edit of the question, google translate may be a bad choice for translating mathematical words (and I'm not talking about texts).

Comment: Why is this getting downvotes? Its a perfectly reasonable question.

Comment: @goblin see the first version of the question

Answer (score 7):

A good way to translate mathematical terms from language $A$ to language $B$ is to look for the wikipedia article of the term in language $A$ and then change it to language $B$.

So look for [manifold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifold) and switch the article to [spanish](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variedad).

Comment: [related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1214574/funny-translations-of-mathematical-words?lq=1)